# User creation in Hyperledger fabric 1.0

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am new to Hyperledger fabric and blockchain.I am trying to build a simple application as part of a POC and completed the ***Getting Started*** tutorial for building the first network. I am very confused about user creation and assigning roles for a specific organization. As I understand, I need to use the ***docker-compose-e2e.yaml***, which starts a **fabric-ca** container to create a public key (certificate) and a private key . Could someone please provide me some instruction or point me to the documentation, on how to create a user, assign a role in an org, get the private and public key, install it on a blockchain network and use it in a chaincode.

Answer (score 2):

Strongly advise that you read and follow the Build Your First Network tutorial in its entirety.

In that tutorial, the users and orgs are created via a configuration file (crypto-config.yaml) which feed the cryptogen command to generate the required key material for orgs and users, etc. This is suitable for a static deployment.

Use of fabric-ca to generate certificates for users etc that can be added via the SDKs is a bit more advanced topic. There's a tutorial in the [Fabric CA User's Guide](http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#fabric-ca-client). This also requires that the MSP used in the fabric network be the Fabric-CA, not the default MSP, which uses the file-based config.